# How to create a WAP in Lubuntu?

Tags: wireless

I am using **Lubuntu 14.04.1**. and my notebook is **Lenovo ThinkPad e531-6885 ERG**, I am connected to the internet through wire (eth0), and i guess it must work because under Windows 7 with MyPublicWifi it just flows amazingly.

So what do I need to do?

btw: the device which should I be able connect is **Nexus 7 (2013)**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Follow the second answer (using `ap-hotspot`).

Comment: thank you very much the second answer with hotspot is already working, is it gonna start automatically with every start of the system?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You can make it start automatically by adding a script to `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` (see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/235367/158442) for an example.