# How do I change proxy settings automatically based on the network that I connect to?

Tags: networking, proxy

I use my laptop at school and at home. However, internet access to each requires different proxy settings. I searched for a way to do this, but I couldn't find a solution, short of manually setting it.

Comment: What proxy settings exactly? APT proxy? Browser proxy? etc. And where do you set them? If there's a command-line way of setting it, this can be done using a Network Manager dispatcher script. (basically what the answer of jdthood comes down to)

Comment: @gertvdijk The system-wide proxy set in Network Settings.  I need it to be system-wide for all processes to access the Internet.

Comment: You can't force all programs to use a proxy. They need to have the support for that and they listen to those settings completely voluntarily. Anyway, would [these scripts](http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/05/quick-tips-change-system-proxy-settings-via-command-line-in-ubuntu-precise.html) help you in combination with a [dispatcher script](http://askubuntu.com/a/187132/88802)?

Answer (score 1):

The author of the program claims that **proxydriver** can do that for you.

- http://marin.jb.free.fr/proxydriver/
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Proxy_settings

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more? Perhaps with a short info about the usage of the software.

Comment: This works for me - install the script manually as per the instructions, connect to your network, edit the created config file and set Firefox to use the system proxy.