# Doing something if connected to particular SSID in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, bash

I want to write a bash script that will put off dropbox automatic synchronization if i'm connected to  particular wifi ssid. How can i catch this event: for example i'm working at home and sync is on, if i'm at another place (cafe, work, etc) auto sync is off.

Also I want to do some other task depending on wifi ssid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a dispatcher script stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` with content for example (not tested):

```
#!/bin/bash
# nm sets this values
INTERFACE=$1
ACTION=$2

SSID="yourssid"
ESSID=`iwconfig $INTERFACE | grep ESSID | cut -d":" -f2 | sed 's/^[^"]*"\|"[^"]*$//g'`

if [ "$INTERFACE" == "wlan0" ]; then
  if [ "$SSID" == "$ESSID" ] && [ "$ACTION" == "up" ]; then
    #activate dropbox sync
  else
    #deactivate dropbox sync
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Why dispatcher and not if-up.d?