# How can I automatically mute my laptop when it connects to my work wifi network?

Tags: automation

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and it would be helpful if I can do this. My phone can do it, my laptop should be able to!

Comment: I've idea for a script that could do that , but right now don't have time to write.

Comment: There used to be a simple app called [Cuttlefish](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/07/execute-actions-when-events-triggered.html) that could do this, but [it looks like it has been abandoned](http://askubuntu.com/questions/583838/cuttlefish-get-it-working-under-14-04-or-suggest-an-alternative). Sorry :/. [This Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/303519/doing-something-if-connected-to-particular-ssid-in-ubuntu) might be a good starting point for devising a script as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer given in the link in Glutanimate's comment, I've written this script that  partially does the job.

```
#!/bin/bash
# nm sets this values
INTERFACE=$1
ACTION=$2

SSID="myworkssid"
ESSID=`nm-tool |grep --only-matching '*[^ ][^:]*' |sed 's/^*//'`

if [ "$INTERFACE" = "wlan0" ]
  then
   if [ "$SSID" = "$ESSID" ] &&  [ "$ACTION" = "up" ]
    then 
    #Mute
        amixer -c 0 set Master playback 0% mute
   else
     #unmute
        amixer -c 0 set Master playback 100% unmute
   fi
fi
```

It has to be copied to /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/
and it has to be executable and owned by root, based on this [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/NetworkManager.8.html).

However, this script only partially does the job because the unmute command doesn't work. If someone can figure out a way to unmute, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Option 1: `amixer set Master toggle`. Option 2: `amixer sset Master unmute; amixer sset PCM unmute; amixer sset "Master Mono" unmute`. Option 3: use `pactl` instead. `pactl set-sink-mute 0 1;
pactl set-sink-mute 0 0`. Sources: http://askubuntu.com/questions/258580/how-to-run-a-script-depending-on-internet-connection; http://www.techytalk.info/start-script-on-network-manager-successful-connection/; http://www.arvydas.co.uk/2012/08/muteunmute-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04-using-command-line/

Comment: I've tried quite a few options with amixer. None of them work. The terminal output is as expected, but the sound output remains muted. I'll try pactl and get back to you!

Comment: I hear that problem with amixer is it has many channels and no single unmute (at least none I know of!). :-) Thus I offered toggle. And pactl, in case it doesn't toggle. ;-) Hope this will help. If it will, feel free to incorporate it in your reply. I've upvoted it already.